# Ionic app sidemenus don't work after closing $ionicPopup

Tags: modal-dialog, ionic-framework, ionic-popup

The Ionic app I'm working on displays a $ionicPopup when it starts and after closing the popup, the two sidemenus the app contains don't work at all. If I remove the popup from the code, the sidemenus work well.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem could be?

Answer (score 0):

Add the following code to the controller that contains the slidebox:

```
    $scope.$on('$ionicView.enter', function(){
    $ionicSlideBoxDelegate.update();
  })
```

I had the same problem than you. I resolved with this.

[Solution](http://forum.ionicframework.com/t/slidebox-and-modal-issue/14370)

Answer (score 0):

I was facing this same problem.

In my case, this was happening because, the `enable-menu-with-back-views="true"` option in `ion-side-menu` was set false.

It got back to work when setting it to true. =)